# Fullforce on iPad 4 uses iPhone keyboard instead of iPad keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, jailbreak, cydia

I've just install the tweak "FullForce" from the Cydia store on my iPad 4th generation to make Google Maps app full screen capable, but the app uses the iPhone keyboard instead of the iPad keyboard.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is not possible to change that. The tweak works, but is limited in what it can do.

Comment: So I have to wait for an update of the tweak, if I have understand well. Thanks!